# Docker/Puppeteer : pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

I'm actually struggling with some thread problems.
I have few errors when I run a node scraper with Puppeteer inside a Docker.

```
Scrape::response() -> Code: 0, error:  Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
,[0427/125747.260079:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(341)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
,[0427/125747.264174:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
,[0427/125747.264480:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
,[0427/125747.269387:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
,[0427/125747.287338:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
,[0427/125747.270779:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
,[0427/125747.287379:FATAL:backend_impl.cc(120)] Check failed: StartWithOptions(base::Thread::Options(base::MessagePumpType::IO, 0)).
,Received signal 6
, r12: 00005610d5ebf038 r13: 00007f7a814fb040 r14: 00007f7a814fae30 r15: 0000000000000085
,  r8: 00007f7a814fa9b4  r9: 00005610d5ec1c20 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
,  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007f7a814fa880  bp: 00007f7a814fa880  bx: 0000000000000000
,  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f7a8965c9e2  sp: 00007f7a814fa878
,  ip: 00007f7a8965c9e2 efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
, trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
,[end of stack trace]
,Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
,TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
,    at onClose (/opt/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
,    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/opt/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:740:61)
,    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:15)
,    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
```

Here's what is displayed when I execute `ulimit -a` :

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1048576
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1048576
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The result of `ps -elfT | wc -l` is **1331**
And `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` returns me 100000.

Here's how I run my my docker, I used some limitation.

```
sh "sudo docker build -f Dockerfile-scraping --build-arg port=${PORT} -t ${DEPLOY_ENV} ."
sh "sudo docker run --pids-limit 100 -m 10G -d -t -p ${PORT}:${PORT} ${DEPLOY_ENV}"
```

I'm using **puppeteer@2.1.0** and my server version is **Debian9**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another application had thread leaks that were causing `OutOfMemory` and   `pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)` errors on the application I was using.

I saw this by using the command `docker stats` ; an application was using like 20k threads and around 30 per seconds.

I hope it could help someone.

Comment: So how did you fix this? I am killing all chrome processes with shelljs pkill chrome but i still get to crash docker with this error